# Checking the validity of an e-mail?

Tags: authentication, gmail, email-spoofing

I was in Court and my ex-wife produced an e-mail that she claims to have sent. Given the nature of this e-mail and following texts, it made no sense but was purely made to prove something she had said to be true when it would have proved the type of character she was. I believe this e-mail wasn’t sent but merely mocked up with some copy and paste skills.

I wasn’t forwarded the e-mail (sent from a gmail account), but a paper copy of it was produced in Court. Would it be possible to check with gmail as to whether the actual e-mail was sent? Obviously things can disappear between sender and recipient but by its contents I don’t believe it was sent.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: A forensic evaluation of the email would be required, which to truly prove anything probably means they would need access to the original senders account. If they're not willing to give access, then it might be arguable that it can't be authenticated. Of course, I'm just a random on the internet. Ask a lawyer.

Answer (score 1):

Google might have it in their logs, but I doubt they'd let you know.

IANAL, but there is one way that could establish that the letter **was** sent - if your ex-wife logged in on her Gmail account, showed that it really was her Gmail account at the court, and showed the mail in the "Sent Items" box. Then the court could also establish to whom it was sent and CC'd - or rather, to which e-mail adresses it was sent and CC'd.

It's not possible to prove that the mail was **not** sent. If the mail is not present in the "Sent Items", she could simply claim that she'd already deleted it from there.

Answer (score 1):

Standard IANAL (nor am I a forensic investigator by any stretch of the imagination). To build on what S.L. Barth had said but I would challenge the validity of *any* "E-mail Evidence" that was not printed with a full set of SMTP Headers.

When an email is sent from one person to another, there is Meta Data that is not seen unless you go looking for it. In Gmail it can be seen by clicking "View Original".

Sample below (obfuscated some of the fields):

```
Return-Path: <sender@gmail.com>
Received: from [10.30.0.208] ([123.123.123.123])
        by smtp.gmail.com with ESMTPSA id n11123asdae.53.2017.03.18.12.34.27
        for <receiver@domain.com>
        (version=TLS1_2 cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 bits=128/128);
        Sat, 18 Mar 2017 12:34:27 -0800 (PST)
From: DKNUCKLES <sender@gmail.com>
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=Apple-Mail-F6FF500D-9577-4180-8332-FBB2009D1611
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Mime-Version: 1.0 (1.0)
Date: Sat, 18 Mar 2017 15:34:27 -0500
Subject: Re: TEST EMAIL
Message-Id: <FDCE2F2D-E4B8-4243-8B0D-395DE53D1888@gmail.com>
References: <YTOPR01MB057036B613C0867C749A60E7D25A0@YTOPR01MB0570.TEST.TEST.TEST.COM>
In-Reply-To: <YTOPR01MB057036B613C0867C749A60E7D25A0@YTOPR01MB0570.TEST.TEST.TEST.COM>
To: Receiver <receiver@domain.com>
X-Mailer: iPhone Mail (14D27)
```

Now the above may look like gibberish to many, however there can be important information in here that could prove or disprove (at the very least, cast considerable doubt) into the authenticity of an email. Yes it is possible that this can be spoofed, however whoever did it would need to know what they're doing.

Interesting Fields

**Received: From** : This is the private then public IP address of the sending network. Was the email supposedly sent from her home? Do you have any emails that *you* sent from her home? Does the Private IP address scheme match? If not likely a potential forgery.

**by smtp.gmail.com with ESMTPSA id....** : This ESMTPSA id is formed based on the date and time sent. If there is a mismatch with these numbers and the "Sending date" then you know this has been forged.

**In-Reply-To (if applicable)** - This information contains the server information of the server this email is in response to. If the sender copied and pasted headers from another email to a different provider (claims to be sending to gmail but actually sent to outlook.com) then this information would be inconsistent.

S.L. Barth is absolutely correct in stating the only real way to confirm authenticity is by seeing the sent items, however if she can't produce the email with a full set of *accurate* headers then you can cast reasonable doubt as to the authenticity of that email.

Comment: Even with SMTP headers, the print should not be proof. If she can't fake the headers herself, all she needs is **one** tech-savvy acquaintance who can.

Comment: @S.L.Barth Totally agree, which is stated in the answer however if you can't produce this right out of the gate then you don't need to proceed to further steps like requesting access to gmail account / logs. Why try to involve third parties that are not likely to co-operate if there's the potential for proof with what should be a standard request for "email transcripts".